# inv(A)*B vs A\B - Why this weird behavior in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, matrix-inverse

Lets create two random matrices,

```
A = randn(2)
B = randn(2)
```

both `inv(A)*B` and `A\B` give the same result

```
inv(A)*B
A\B

ans =

    0.6175   -2.1988
   -0.7522    5.0343

ans =

    0.6175   -2.1988
   -0.7522    5.0343
```

**unless** I multiply with some factor. Why is this?

```
.5*A\B
.5*inv(A)*B

ans =

    1.2349   -4.3977
   -1.5045   10.0685

ans =

    0.3087   -1.0994
   -0.3761    2.5171
```

This is very annoying since MatLab always nudges me to use `A\B` instead of `inv(A)*B` and it took me years to figure out why my code was not working.

Comment: 0.5*(A\B) !! You are doing (0.5*A)\B!

Comment: For reference: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html . Do note that "Within each precedence level, operators have equal precedence and are evaluated from left to right."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `A` is **non-singular matrix**, then `inv(A) * B = A \ B`.

Your calculation is as follows: `.5 * A\B = (0.5 * A) \ B` vs `.5* inv(A) * B = 0.5 * (A\B)` . As such, it will give your unequal result.